# Delete all the last node of linked list which have value = 0

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a linked list like this: `1 0 1 2 0 0 0`.
I want to delete all the last "0" node so my list can look like: `1 0 1 2`.
I tried using recursion:

```
Node *trimtList(Node* head) {
    if (head->next->data == 0 && head->next->next == NULL) {
        head->next = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    trimList(head->next);
    return head;
}
```

I realize that this method is just delete the last 0, not all the last 0...

```
Node *trimtList(Node* head) {
    if (head && !trimtList(head->next) && head->data == 0) {
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
    }
    return head;
}

int main() {
    List a;
    a.head= new Node(1);
    a.head->next = new Node(0);
    a.head->next->next = new Node(2);
    a.head->next->next->next = new Node(0);
    a.head->next->next->next->next = new Node(0);
    a.head= trimtList(a.head);
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

The output is `1 0 2 2` and then windows has stop working...

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
Node *trimList(Node* head) {
    if (trimList(head->next).next == NULL && head->next->data == 0 ) {
        head->next = NULL;
    }

    return head;
}
```

By calling trimList at the beginning rather than at the end we make sure that there is at most one 0 node ahead of ours.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my five cents.:)

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void push_front( Node * &head, int data )
{
    Node *tmp = new Node { data, head };
    head = tmp;
}

std::ostream & display( Node * &head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( Node *tmp = head; tmp; tmp = tmp->next )
    {
        os << tmp->data << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}    

Node * rtrim( Node * &head, int data = 0 )
{
    if ( head && !rtrim( head->next, data ) && head->data == data )
    {
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
    }

    return head;
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = nullptr;

    for ( int x : { 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1 } ) push_front( head, x );
    display( head ) << std::endl;

    rtrim( head );
    display( head ) << std::endl;

    rtrim( head, 2 );
    display( head ) << std::endl;

    rtrim( head, 1 );
    display( head ) << std::endl;

    rtrim( head );
    display( head ) << std::endl;

    rtrim( head, 1 );
    display( head ) << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 0 1 2 0 0 0 
1 0 1 2 
1 0 1 
1 0 
1
```

Shortly speaking your own function can look like

```
Node *trimtList(Node* head) {
    if ( head && !trimList( head->next ) && head->data == 0 ) {
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
    }

    return head;
}
```

and should be called like

```
head = trimtList( head );
```